# Access java classes inside .jar in Jruby

Tags: java, ruby, jruby

I am currently developing my Jruby application which is contained inside a .jar file.

Within the jar, my file structure looks like this:

```
lib/launch.rb
lib/src/class1.rb
       /class2.rb
lib/com/class1.class
       /class2.class
```

Where 'class1.class' and 'class2.class' are compiled using `jrubyc class1.rb` and `jrubyc class2.rb`

I want to access these methods within 'class1.class' and 'class2.class' inside 'launch.rb'.

```
#launch.rb 

require 'java'
$CLASSPATH << "com" 
java_import 'class1'
java_import 'class2'
```

But, I am currently running into this issue :

```
NameError: cannot load Java class 'class1'
```

Is there another way to import and access these methods within class1 and class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`com` sounds like the package name, what you want is add **lib** to CP :

```
$CLASSPATH << File.expand_path('lib')
# now import the class with the full name (including package) :
java_import 'com.class1'
# ... or simply just :
Java::com.class1
```

but assuming its a (compiled) .rb script, maybe you just want to load it:

```
$LOAD_PATH << 'lib'
require 'class1'
```